# Dual Space Annihilator in C[0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $V = C[0,1]$ and let U be the subspace of functions of the form 
$y(x) = ax+b$ for some a, b depending on the function.  Give an explicit family of functionals $F\subset U^\perp$ such that for any $y \in V$ satisfying f(y) = 0$\ \  \forall f \in F$, we have$\  y\in U$.

In other words, in $V^{**}$, we have$$span F^\perp\cap\phi(V) = \phi(U).$$

Help Please

Comment: Do you know what is the dual space of $C[0,1]$?

Comment: I dont and this is an intriguing question to me, what's this dual space?  My teacher hasn't explained the concept very clearly @JankoBracic

Comment: This is from Wikipedia:The Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem gives a characterization of the continuous dual space of C(X). Specifically, this dual space is the space of Radon measures on X (regular Borel measures), denoted by rca(X). This space, with the norm given by the total variation of a measure, is also a Banach space belonging to the class of ba spaces. (Dunford & Schwartz 1958, §IV.6.3) See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_functions_on_a_compact_Hausdorff_space

Comment: How does this help in answering the question though?

Comment: Note that in particular the evaluation functionals $\delta_t \colon f \mapsto f(t)$ belong to $V^\ast$ (whether that's the algebraic or the topological dual) for all $t\in [0,1]$. You can take $F$ as a family of suitable linear combinations of these evaluation functionals.

Comment: @George, does my answer give enough detail? If not, let me know what you would like to see. (Knowing the whole dual space of $V$ is not necessary here, it's enough to know some elements of it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function is affine if and only if its second derivative vanishes.
We only have continuous functions here, but this idea can still be made work, but we have to resort to a discrete second derivative.

For $a\in[0,1]$, let $\delta_a:V\to\mathbb R$ be the evaluation functional at $a$, $\delta_a(f)=f(a)$.
(This is continuous in the usual topology of $V$ if you are interested in the topological dual. Here it doesn't really matter if it is the algebraic or the topological one.)
We will only use sums of functionals like this.

For $(a,b)\in[0,1]^2$, denote $f_{a,b}=\delta_a-2\delta_{(a+b)/2}+\delta_b$.
Now let
$$
F=\{f_{a,b};(a,b)\in[0,1]^2\}.
$$

**Claim:**
For $y\in V$ the following are equivalent:

1. $y\in U$
2. $f(y)=0$ for all $f\in F$.

**Proof:**
If $y\in U$, it is a simple calculation to observe that $f(y)=0$ for all $f\in F$.
Proving the other direction is the harder part.

Suppose $y\in V$ is annihilated by all $f\in F$.
There is an element $z\in U$ so that $y(0)=z(0)$ and $y(1)=z(1)$.
(This $z$ is actually unique.)
Let $w=y-z$.
We know that $w\in V$ and we will show that in fact $w=0$; from this it will follow that $y=z\in U$.

By construction $w(0)=0$ and $w(1)=0$.
We also know that $f_{0,1}(w)=w(0)-2w(1/2)+w(1)=0$, so $w(1/2)=0$.
Now we can use $w(0)=w(1/2)=0$ and $f_{0,1/2}(w)=0$ to get $w(1/4)=0$ and similarly $w(3/4)=0$.
If $w$ vanishes at two points, it has to vanish in their midpoint as well.
Continuing inductively, we find that for any $n>1$ and $1<m<2^n$ our function satisfies $w(2^{-n}m)=0$.
But points like this are dense in $[0,1]$ and $w$ is continuous, so in fact $w(x)=0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.
$\square$

Comment: Only saw this now, the answer is excellent thank you very much

Comment: Neat solution! Very insightful.